# Check if a file is empty?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am building an app to check the contents of a csv file. I am able to check the rows and columns properly. Now, I want to find out if the entire file is empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If by "empty" you mean it has absolutely nothing in it (0 bytes) you could do something like this:

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([manager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
    NSDictionary *attributes = [manager attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil];
    unsigned long long size = [attributes fileSize];
    if (attributes && size == 0) {
        // file exists, but is empty.
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the path variable here?